# Severe limitation for QWebView

Tags: qt, qwebview

I have a table inside HTML I am submitting to a QWebView.

The table grows during the lifecycle of the application.

If I manage the html QString on the side and just "setHtml" with every update I run into a performance problem where adding 1000 rows to the table takes minutes.

Isn't there a way for me to access the HTML directly on the QWebView and inject the new table row every time, updating the html directly?

Comment: should i use javascript? just call a javascript function to inject the new table rows? is it possible to call a javascript function from QWebView in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is to interact with the [QWebFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html), which is the lowest level object. You can access it via:  `QWebView->page()->mainFrame()`

From the `QWebFrame`, you could either use [`evaluateJavaScript()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) to simply send snippets to the page for execution.

Or you can register a QObject with the frame using [`addToJavaScriptWindowObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject),  that bridges between your Qt code and the javascript page. You can read [more in detail here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html). But this approach would let the javascript-side define a function as a "slot" and connect to a signal defined on your QObject, such as `updateTable()`. Then whenever you do something on the Qt side and emit the data with that signal, the javascript will catch it and handle it.

**Qt**

```
 QWebFrame *frame = myWebPage->mainFrame();
 frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("tableHandler", tableHandlerObject);
```

**Javscript**

```
 function handleTableUpdate() { ... }
 ...
 tableHandler.updateReady.connect(handleTableUpdate);
```